# Different results from check_property and msat_check_ltlspec_bmc in NuXMV

Tags: model-checking, nuxmv

The following property is true with check_property but msat_check_ltlspec_bmc gives counterexample. The result of latter one seems to be correct."G (((tt >= 7) -> G ((FlagLO = FALSE)))) IN module". how do we explain this?

I tried this with slightly changed smv file. Was trying to check the existence pattern based LTL property.
Check_fsm result was not run earlier. This gives a deadlock. In that case msat_check.... result seems incorrect.
Now which one is correct? And what should be the correct method of verifying the model? Need to work with reals, thus trying msat commands.

```
MODULE Seq_19(T_41, T_41_PRESENT)
    VAR
        _next_t : { Init_46_idle, LO_51_idle, BO_73_idle, State_120_idle, TO_132_idle, LOSense_118, BOSense_115, TOSense_137, TransitionSegment_125, BOSense_141 };
        FlagLO : boolean;
        FlagBO : boolean;
        tt : -256..255;
        FlagTO : boolean;

    DEFINE
        LOOut_68 := 
            case
                (_next_t = LOSense_118) : TRUE;
                TRUE : FALSE;
            esac;
        BOOut_84 := 
            case
                (_next_t = BOSense_115) : TRUE;
                (_next_t = BOSense_141) : TRUE;
                TRUE : FALSE;
            esac;
        LOOut_68_PRESENT := 
            case
                (_next_t = LOSense_118) : TRUE;
                TRUE : FALSE;
            esac;
        BOOut_84_PRESENT := 
            case
                (_next_t = BOSense_115) : TRUE;
                (_next_t = BOSense_141) : TRUE;
                TRUE : FALSE;
            esac;
        guard_LOSense_118 := (tt > 5);
        guard_BOSense_115 := (tt > 10);
        guard_TOSense_137 := (tt > 8);
        guard_TransitionSegment_125 := (tt > 50);
        guard_BOSense_141 := (tt > 10);

    ASSIGN
        init(_next_t) := { Init_46_idle, LOSense_118 };
        init(FlagLO) := FALSE;
        init(FlagBO) := FALSE;
        init(tt) := 0;
        init(FlagTO) := FALSE;

    TRANS _next_t in { Init_46_idle }
         -> next(_next_t) in { Init_46_idle, LOSense_118 };
    TRANS _next_t in { LO_51_idle, LOSense_118 }
         -> next(_next_t) in { LO_51_idle, BOSense_115, TOSense_137 };
    TRANS _next_t in { BO_73_idle, BOSense_115, BOSense_141 }
         -> next(_next_t) in { BO_73_idle, TransitionSegment_125 };
    TRANS _next_t in { State_120_idle, TransitionSegment_125 }
         -> next(_next_t) in { State_120_idle };
    TRANS _next_t in { TO_132_idle, TOSense_137 }
         -> next(_next_t) in { TO_132_idle, BOSense_141 };
    TRANS (_next_t = Init_46_idle)
         -> next(tt) = (tt + 1) &
            next(FlagLO) = FlagLO &
            next(FlagBO) = FlagBO &
            next(FlagTO) = FlagTO;
    TRANS (_next_t = LO_51_idle)
         -> next(tt) = (tt + 1) &
            next(FlagLO) = FlagLO &
            next(FlagBO) = FlagBO &
            next(FlagTO) = FlagTO;
    TRANS (_next_t = BO_73_idle)
         -> next(tt) = (tt + 1) &
            next(FlagLO) = FlagLO &
            next(FlagBO) = FlagBO &
            next(FlagTO) = FlagTO;
    TRANS (_next_t = State_120_idle)
         -> next(tt) = (tt + 1) &
            next(FlagLO) = FlagLO &
            next(FlagBO) = FlagBO &
            next(FlagTO) = FlagTO;
    TRANS (_next_t = TO_132_idle)
         -> next(tt) = (tt + 1) &
            next(FlagLO) = FlagLO &
            next(FlagBO) = FlagBO &
            next(FlagTO) = FlagTO;
    TRANS (_next_t = LOSense_118)
         -> next(FlagLO) = TRUE &
            next(tt) = (tt + 1) &
            next(FlagBO) = FlagBO &
            next(FlagTO) = FlagTO;
    TRANS (_next_t = BOSense_115)
         -> next(FlagBO) = TRUE &
            next(tt) = (tt + 1) &
            next(FlagLO) = FlagLO &
            next(FlagTO) = FlagTO;
    TRANS (_next_t = TOSense_137)
         -> next(FlagTO) = TRUE &
            next(tt) = (tt + 1) &
            next(FlagLO) = FlagLO &
            next(FlagBO) = FlagBO;
    TRANS (_next_t = TransitionSegment_125)
         -> next(tt) = (tt + 1) &
            next(FlagLO) = FlagLO &
            next(FlagBO) = FlagBO &
            next(FlagTO) = FlagTO;
    TRANS (_next_t = BOSense_141)
         -> next(FlagBO) = TRUE &
            next(tt) = (tt + 1) &
            next(FlagLO) = FlagLO &
            next(FlagTO) = FlagTO;

    INVAR ((_next_t = LOSense_118) -> guard_LOSense_118)
    INVAR ((_next_t = BOSense_115) -> guard_BOSense_115)
    INVAR ((_next_t = TOSense_137) -> guard_TOSense_137)
    INVAR ((_next_t = TransitionSegment_125) -> guard_TransitionSegment_125)
    INVAR ((_next_t = BOSense_141) -> guard_BOSense_141)
    INVAR ((_next_t = Init_46_idle) -> !(guard_LOSense_118))
    INVAR ((_next_t = LO_51_idle) -> (!(guard_BOSense_115) & !(guard_TOSense_137)))
    INVAR ((_next_t = BO_73_idle) -> !(guard_TransitionSegment_125))
    INVAR ((_next_t = State_120_idle) -> TRUE)
    INVAR ((_next_t = TO_132_idle) -> !(guard_BOSense_141))

MODULE main
    VAR
        T_41 : -256..255;
        T_41_PRESENT : boolean;
        module : Seq_19(T_41,T_41_PRESENT);
```

This is the output of `msat_check_ltlspec_bmc`:

```
nuXmv > read_model -i Seq.smv
nuXmv > go_msat
nuXmv > msat_check_ltlspec_bmc -p "G (((tt >= 7) -> G ((FlagLO = FALSE)))) IN module"
-- no counterexample found with bound 0
-- no counterexample found with bound 1
-- no counterexample found with bound 2
-- no counterexample found with bound 3
-- no counterexample found with bound 4
-- no counterexample found with bound 5
-- no counterexample found with bound 6
-- specification  G (tt >= 7 ->  G FlagLO = FALSE) IN module is false
-- as demonstrated by the following execution sequence
Trace Description: MSAT BMC counterexample
Trace Type: Counterexample
  -> State: 1.1 <-
    T_41 = -256
    T_41_PRESENT = FALSE
    module._next_t = Init_46_idle
    module.FlagLO = FALSE
    module.FlagBO = FALSE
    module.tt = 0
    module.FlagTO = FALSE
    module.guard_BOSense_141 = FALSE
    module.guard_TransitionSegment_125 = FALSE
    module.guard_TOSense_137 = FALSE
    module.guard_BOSense_115 = FALSE
    module.guard_LOSense_118 = FALSE
    module.BOOut_84_PRESENT = FALSE
    module.LOOut_68_PRESENT = FALSE
    module.BOOut_84 = FALSE
    module.LOOut_68 = FALSE
  -> State: 1.2 <-
    T_41 = 255
    T_41_PRESENT = TRUE
    module.tt = 1
  -> State: 1.3 <-
    T_41 = -238
    T_41_PRESENT = FALSE
    module.tt = 2
  -> State: 1.4 <-
    T_41 = 255
    T_41_PRESENT = TRUE
    module.tt = 3
  -> State: 1.5 <-
    T_41 = -224
    T_41_PRESENT = FALSE
    module.tt = 4
  -> State: 1.6 <-
    T_41 = 255
    T_41_PRESENT = TRUE
    module.tt = 5
  -> State: 1.7 <-
    module._next_t = LOSense_118
    module.tt = 6
    module.guard_LOSense_118 = TRUE
    module.LOOut_68_PRESENT = TRUE
    module.LOOut_68 = TRUE
  -> State: 1.8 <-
    module._next_t = LO_51_idle
    module.FlagLO = TRUE
    module.tt = 7
    module.LOOut_68_PRESENT = FALSE
    module.LOOut_68 = FALSE
```

This is the output of a normal LTL `check_property` call:

```
nuXmv > go
nuXmv > check_property -l -p "G (((tt >= 7) -> G ((FlagLO = FALSE)))) IN module"
-- specification  G (tt >= 7 ->  G FlagLO = FALSE) IN module is true
```

This is the output of `check_fsm`:

```
nuXmv > check_fsm

********   WARNING   ********
Fair states set of the finite state machine is empty.
This might make results of model checking not trustable.
******** END WARNING ********

##########################################################
The transition relation is not total. A state without
successors is:
T_41 = -256
T_41_PRESENT = FALSE
module._next_t = State_120_idle
module.FlagLO = FALSE
module.FlagBO = FALSE
module.tt = 255
module.FlagTO = FALSE
The transition relation is not deadlock-free.
A deadlock state is:
T_41 = -256
T_41_PRESENT = FALSE
module._next_t = State_120_idle
module.FlagLO = TRUE
module.FlagBO = TRUE
module.tt = 255
module.FlagTO = TRUE
##########################################################
```

Comment: See [FAQ #010](http://nusmv.fbk.eu/faq.html#010) and  [FAQ #011](http://nusmv.fbk.eu/faq.html#011), since the FSM has a deadlock the result of LTL model checking with Tableau-based techniques cannot be trusted. Please edit your transition relation to be deadlock-free. The BMC technique likely didn't fail because the counter-example appears before the deadlock state in terms of depth of the execution trace. I would still fix the transition relation.

Comment: Yes. I will fix the transition relation. Thank you so much for this explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of `check_fsm` tells you where the problem is: there are **deadlock** states in your *FSM*.

See [FAQ #011](http://nusmv.fbk.eu/faq.html#011)

> BDD based LTL model checking algorithms implemented in NuSMV reason
>   only about infinite paths. Thus, even for a safety property that does
>   not hold, a lasso-shaped counterexample is generated, although a
>   finite path would be enough. While doing the check, it is assumed the
>   totality of the transition relation and the absence of deadlocks, and
>   the search is restricted to consider only infinite paths, disregarding
>   all paths leading to a deadlock. Thus, a finite path leading to a
>   deadlock and falsifying the property will not be detected.
>
> SAT based bounded model checking algorithms also assume the totality
>   of the transition relation and the absence of deadlocks, but they are
>   looking for a counterexample for the given property that is either
>   finite or infinite. Thus, differently from the BDD based LTL model
>   checking algorithms, a finite path leading to a deadlock and
>   falsifying the property will be detected.
>
> Both algorithms assume the totality of the transition relation and the
>   absence of deadlocks but they do not specifically check for these
>   conditions being satisfied. It is the user responsibility to perform
>   this check by e.g. issuing the -ctt command line flag in batch mode,
>   or by invoking the check_fsm command in the NuSMV shell.
>
> Up to now there is no flag to disable the search for a finite path
>   within SAT based bounded model checking. However, by adding within the
>   model the following justice fairness condition
>
> JUSTICE TRUE;
>
> the bounded model checking algorithms stop looking for a finite path
>   and restrict the search to only infinite paths:
>
> Another possible difference in the reported verification results can
>   be happen when the NuSMV model contains more than one initial state.
>   The BDD based approach relies on the reduction of LTL model checking
>   to CTL model checking (via tableau construction). CTL model checking
>   universally quantify over the set of fair initial states. Thus, only
>   initial states that are fair are considered. There can be initial
>   states that are not fair, and they are not considered. This choice can
>   be questionable, but it is also shown by CadenceSMV. Differently, BMC
>   based model checking does not restrict to consider only fair initial
>   states. Thus, if there exists an initial state that is not fair and
>   from which there is a finite path violates the fairness conditions it
>   will find it.

Comment: Why there is no CTL based checking using BMC techniques? Is there any reference available?

Comment: @RanjanaN In the literature there are a few papers on BMC applied to CTL model checking, or a fragment thereof. Since I am not part of the development team, I cannot give an answer  for NuSMV/nuXmv on their account.

Comment: Thank you for this clarification. Another question is that Is there any tutorial or examples on SMT based commands usage for NuXMV? The commands which run after go_msat.